# How backup and restore only list(name) databases, roles and right for databases in postgresql without data?

Tags: postgresql, psql, pg-dump

How backup and restore only list(name) databases, roles and right for databases in postgresql without data?

Bash script for get list database postgresql

```
sudo -i -u postgres psql  -t -A -c 'SELECT datname FROM pg_database'
```

But how restore databases and relationship for roles and databases in postgresql?

Vao Tsun answer:

> to prepare sql with database list for creation use smth like: psql -c
>   "select 'create database '||datname||';' from pg_database where not
>   datistemplate and datname != 'postgres';" -At >cdbs.sql, to create
>   database from a list, use psql -f cdbs.sql against new cluster

But all restored databases have owner postgres.
How restore databases with owner?
Thanks

Comment: right for relations without relations?..

Answer (score 0):

from top of the head - try:

1. to get all roles, use `pg_dumpall -g`
2. to get permissions use `pg_dump -s >to_file.sql` and then `psql -f to_file.sql` ignoring creations errors.
3. to prepare sql with database list for creation use smth like: `psql -c "select 'create database '||datname||';' from pg_database where not datistemplate and datname != 'postgres';" -At >cdbs.sql`, to create database from a list, use `psql -f cdbs.sql` against new cluster

Comment: But how create databases from list ?

Comment: added to the answer

Comment: how create databases from list? Thanks

Comment: just apply generated lines against new cluster. updated answer

Comment: Can you write small example?

Comment: I did! all three point have axect command to run - you have errors?

Comment: O Thanks. I will try

Comment: DB restored. But all restored databases have owner postgres.
How restore databases with owner?
Thanks

Comment: @AntonPatsev please ask it in separate question, as it is not specific for your question